# Loop splitting separation issue

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am making a loop with these data. I have one problem: When I print the dates, it comes out: '2015.12.**0919**:45123.251',... I want to avoid to many loops so it wont be slowed down.

```
for line in sline:
    parts = line.split(',')
```

It only seperate by "," But in the csv there is a "." in between the date and the time. This of course confuse the code and makes it print 0919 with no sepatation inbetween the date and time.

There are 60.000 rows in the excel/csv file. How do I either change the "," to "." in all the rows in excel. Or program it in the code so it will change it or understand it.

> 2015.12.09,19:45,123.287,123.324,123.149,123.251,2914
>   2015.12.09,20:00,123.249,123.288,123.081,123.188,4000
>   2015.12.09,20:15,123.189,123.243,123.073,123.192,3463
>   2015.12.09,20:30,123.193,123.267,123.119,123.242,3561

The full code reading the csv:

```
lst = list()

with open("CHFJPY15.csv", "r") as f:
    f_r = f.read()

    sline = f_r.split()

    for line in sline:
        parts = line.split(',')
        date = parts[0]
        time = parts[1]
        closeingtime = parts[5]

        timestamp = date + time + closeingtime

        lst.append(timestamp)
print(lst, "liste")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just need to add spaces:

```
timestamp = date + ' ' + time + ' ' + closeingtime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the the_string.replace(to_replace, what_to_replace_with) function. It should help you with switching between commas and periods.